# Crear un diccionario a partir de una lista con key duplicados

Tags: python

**Input**

```
my_list = 
    [key1, value1,
    key2, value2,
    key3, value3,
    key1, value4,
    key1, value5,
    key2, value6]
```

**Output**

```
my_dic = {
key1: [value1, value4, value5],
key2: [value2, value6]
key3, [value3] }
```

Como puedo crear un diccionario de la forma
key:[values] en caso de que el key sea el mismo.

Comment: Los diccionarios en `Python` no soportan duplicados de llaves, tendrías que hacerlo creando tal vez una clase o utilizando `defaultdict` de `collections`

Comment: Itera por tu lista, para cada elemento, (que es una lista `clave`, `valor`) mira si la `clave` ya estaba en el `diccionario` y si no lo estaba añadela dandole como valor una lista `[valor]`. Si ya estaba, añade a `diccionario[clave]ˋ el nuevo valor, usando `.append()`

Comment: SI al menos publicaras un código a partir del cual trabajar. Tal como está, es más trabajo tipear los valores que escribir la solución